# Burndown and Burn Rate Charts in TFS 2010 Project Portal Personal vs Shared View

Tags: 2010, tfs

This is my first question, so please bear with me. I'll try and be as detailed as I can. I also hope this is the appropriate place for this.

Our team is using the MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0 with TFS 2010 and the default Sharepoint that comes with that (WSS 3.0, I believe; I know for sure it's the default that comes with TFS 2010 since I know we didn't do anything crazy with that).

What I'm trying to do is make it so that the aforementioned charts display different information in the Project Dashboard view and the My Dashboard view. The reason for this is that we have a team project - we'll call it "Master Project" - which has all the code and all the checkins happen there. Through an overwhelmingly brilliant stroke of genius, someone decided to start a new "project" as a sub-project of Master Project (we'll call this "Sub Project") in the form of new TFS iterations and areas, which is where all the user stories and tasks for Sub Project are being created. All code checkins still happen in Master Project, however, which I guess is why they organized these projects this way. The BA in charge of Sub Project would like to see the Task Burndown and Burn Rate charts, but only for the appropriate iterations and areas that represent Sub Project, so I thought we should use the My Dashboard for this user to contain these, so we don't mess with Master Project's graphs in Project Dashboard.

What happens is this: no matter what I do, the Task Burndown and Burn Rate graphs in My Dashboard and Project Dashboard always both display the same information.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Go to My Dashboard, add the graphs, and customize them to display the proper iterations and areas by selecting Edit Page from the Site Actions menu, selecting Modify My Web Part from the 'edit' menu of the appropriate graph, and copy/pasting all the pertinent properties from the same graph in Project Dashboard. After this, I changed the Link property to have ShowToolbar=1, which allows me to change the parameters of the report after hitting Apply, so I do this, change the parameters, revert the Link property back, and then hit OK. The result is that the graph now displays the specific iteration/area graph on the My Dashboard page (good) AND the main Project Dashboard page (not what I had in mind...).
2. I've also tried switching to "personal view" by finding the Personalize this Page link in the Welcome menu at the top-right and utilizing a similar approach, and the same result happens: all Task Burndown and Burn Rate graphs are updated, not just the ones that appear in the 'personalized' view of My Dashboard.
3. I've tried removing the default parameter from the reports through the reports server, hoping maybe the user can be prompted for it, but this ends up causing the following error "This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'IterationParam'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value.". Stupid solution, I know, but I'm getting desperate here.
4. I suppose I could teach the BA to go into these and change them according to #1 above every two weeks, but this person is not a developer, so this process would be quite cumbersome for them, and still doesn't even solve the issue of having just THEIR graphs updated..
5. Teaching this BA to log into SSMS's Analysis Services and navigating the TFS data warehouse to find the appropriate MDX query for their iterations and areas would be even more cumbersome and ridiculous than #4, in my opinion (remember, this person is not a developer)

There has to be a way to accomplish this, unless M$ has some excuse why they don't allow it.. Does anyone know if this is even possible? Also, I'm pretty sure there's at least a chance that the geniuses who decided to organize Master Project and Sub Project this way caused this headache with their decision to do so. Also, in an attempt to garner more sympathy, there are multiple projects that are setup just like Sub Project here.. :)